# Code behind not found at runtime

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, code-behind

I've an ASP.NET application running fine locally, I've published the site and copied all files up to the live server and all is not good.

99% of the pages are doing just as they should be, but just two pages are complaining that they can't find the code behind file?  This is kind of urgent (demo tomorrow), so any help appreciated.  Error message below...

Thanks,

ETFairfax.

> Parser Error Message: The file
>   '/CompanyRoot/_ReactiveTaskManagement/ReactiveTaskPage/ReactiveTaskEdit.aspx.cs'
>   does not exist.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page
>   Theme="ReactiveTaskManagament"
>   Language="C#"
>   MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/EditMaster.master"
>   Line 2:      AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeFile="ReactiveTaskEdit.aspx.cs"
>   Inherits="FacilityManager.Web.WebApplication._ReactiveTaskManagement.ReactiveTaskPage.ReactiveTaskEdit"
>   %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the files are included in the solution in Visual Studio?
If its a complied assembly (dll) that you're deploying I think you take the `codefile` attribute off your markup file.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the CodeFile attribute.  At 2am in the morning I was just staring at it!!!!  Thanks again.